# ¿Cómo convertir consulta SQL SERVER a formato JSON específico?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, transact-sql

Ejecuto la siguiente consulta a unas tablas temporales después de crear unos PIVOT .

```
 SELECT urlYoutube AS Url, apiKeyYoutube AS Token, canalIdYoutube AS Id FROM #YoutubeFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlFlickr AS Url, apiKeyflickr AS Token,userIdFlickr AS Id  FROM #FlickrFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlInstagram AS Url , tokenInstagram AS Token ,col3 AS Id FROM #InstagramFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlFacebook AS Url ,col2 AS Token,col3 AS Id FROM #FacebookFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlTwitter AS Url,col2 AS Token ,col3 AS Id  FROM #TwitterFeatures FOR JSON PATH
```

Y me devuelve un Json con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
 {"Id":"fdytdTYKJHFVftf"},
 {"Id":"GHFGHFH6567cgghcfgxc"},
 {"Token":"dfgdf546sfgssgg"},
 {"Token":"dfsfdHVHGC455657"},
 {"Token":"FVHGCTD67567467GHCHFGCfcfgcxfgxg"},
 {"Url":"https:\/\/graph.instagram.com\/me\/fgdfgdf"},
 {"Url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/gdfg5464fdgdfg"},
 {"Url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com/jadgha12375vjh"},
 {"Url":"https:\/\/www.flickr.com\/services\/rest\/?gdfgd"},
 {"Url":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/youtube\/v3\/"}
]
```

Pero necesito que me devuelva un JSON para deserializarlo en la siguiente clase:

```
public class SocialFeaturesModel
{
  public Propertys Youtube{get;set;}
  public Propertys Flickr {get;set;}
  public Propertys Instagram {get;set;}
  public Propertys Facebook {get;set;}
  public Propertys Twitter {get;set;}
}
    public class Propertys
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Aqui el procedimiento almacenado completo:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

    
    CREATE TABLE  #YoutubeFeatures ( urlYoutube VARCHAR(255), apiKeyYoutube VARCHAR(255), canalIdYoutube VARCHAR(255));
    CREATE TABLE  #FlickrFeatures ( urlFlickr VARCHAR(255), apiKeyFlickr VARCHAR(255) ,userIdFlickr VARCHAR(255));
    CREATE TABLE  #InstagramFeatures ( urlInstagram  VARCHAR(255), tokenInstagram VARCHAR(255),col3 VARCHAR(255));
    CREATE TABLE  #FacebookFeatures ( urlFacebook  VARCHAR(255),col2 VARCHAR(255),col3 VARCHAR(255));
    CREATE TABLE  #TwitterFeatures ( urlTwitter  VARCHAR(255),col2 VARCHAR(255),col3 VARCHAR(255));

    INSERT INTO #YoutubeFeatures (urlYoutube, apiKeyYoutube , canalIdYoutube)
    SELECT urlYoutube, apiKeyYoutube , canalIdYoutube FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ViewSocialFeatures WHERE name LIKE '%Youtube%' ) y
    PIVOT( MAX(translation) FOR name IN (urlYoutube, apiKeyYoutube , canalIdYoutube )) AS pivot_youtube;

    INSERT INTO #FlickrFeatures (urlFlickr, apiKeyFlickr,userIdFlickr)
    SELECT urlFlickr, apiKeyflickr,userIdFlickr FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ViewSocialFeatures WHERE name LIKE '%Flickr%' ) f
    PIVOT( MAX(translation) FOR name IN (urlFlickr, apiKeyFlickr,userIdFlickr)) AS pivot_flicker;

    INSERT INTO #InstagramFeatures (urlInstagram, tokenInstagram,col3)
    SELECT urlInstagram, tokenInstagram,col3 FROM(SELECT * FROM dbo.ViewSocialFeatures WHERE name LIKE '%Instagram%' ) i 
    PIVOT(MAX(translation) FOR name IN (urlInstagram, tokenInstagram,col3)) AS pivot_instagram;

    INSERT INTO  #FacebookFeatures (urlFacebook,col2,col3)
    SELECT urlFacebook,col2,col3 FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ViewSocialFeatures WHERE name LIKE '%Facebook%' ) fb
    PIVOT(MAX(translation) FOR name IN (urlFacebook,col2,col3)) AS pivot_facebook;

    INSERT INTO   #TwitterFeatures (urlTwitter,col2,col3)
    SELECT urlTwitter,col2,col3 FROM (SELECT * FROM dbo.ViewSocialFeatures WHERE name LIKE '%Twitter%' ) t 
    PIVOT( MAX(translation)FOR name IN (urlTwitter,col2,col3)) AS pivot_twitter;


    SELECT urlYoutube AS Url, apiKeyYoutube AS Token, canalIdYoutube AS Id FROM #YoutubeFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlFlickr AS Url, apiKeyflickr AS Token,userIdFlickr AS Id  FROM #FlickrFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlInstagram AS Url , tokenInstagram AS Token ,col3 AS Id FROM #InstagramFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlFacebook AS Url ,col2 AS Token,col3 AS Id FROM #FacebookFeatures UNION
    SELECT urlTwitter AS Url,col2 AS Token ,col3 AS Id  FROM #TwitterFeatures FOR JSON PATH
    

    END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            Declare @error nvarchar(max)
            Set @error = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
                            ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
                            ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
                            FOR JSON PATH , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER);
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            SELECT 'FAIL' Result, @error 'Message' FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

quizá usando la librería Newtonsoft para convertir el JSON que obtienes de la base de datos en un diccionario de tipo Dictionary<string, string>, en donde luego mediante las llaves del diccionario, crees objetos de tipo SocialFeaturesModel con todos los valores que quieres en sus respectivas property's